# Using C#, how to identify if it's a sine wave by reading a file containing time and sample values of a waveform taken from oscilloscope?

Tags: c#, algorithm, signal-processing, waveform, sine-wave

I have a text file containing time and sample values of a waveform taken from an oscilloscope. 
How do i identify by reading the samples, that it is a sine wave?
Is there a way to identify if the waveform is clipped, has a constant amplitude etc?
This has to be done in C#.

Comment: This is a rather broad question and more about math than C#. I'm not a mathematician so am not sure about this, but you may want to try the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) forum and come back to StackOverflow if you have problems with the coding part of things.

Comment: This might be a good fit for the Data Science SE as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do an inverse Fourier transform over the data and check if there is only a single frequency in the results.